# How to log Laravel get and post requests

Tags: php, laravel

How can I log all post and get requests going in and out of  Laravel Luma ?

Our routes look like this :

```
    $router->group(['prefix' => 'mini'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('/', 'Controller@index');
    $router->post('/', 'Controller@index');
    $router->get('/paginate', 'Controller@paginate');
    $router->post('/paginate', 'Controller@paginate');
    $router->get('/debug', 'Controller@debug');
    $router->post('/debug', 'Controller@debug');
    $router->get('/debug_sql', 'Controller@debug_sql');
    $router->post('/debug_sql', 'Controller@debug_sql');
});
```

Comment: create a middleware to do it

Comment: Maybe with a profiler / profiling solution or auto_prepend_file (for incoming requests).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create a middleware:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class LogRequest
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        app('log')->info("Request Captured", $request->all());

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Then reference it in your `bootstrap/app.php`:

```php
$app->middleware([
     App\Http\Middleware\LogRequest::class
]);
```

This will produce the following in your lumen.log:

```
[2022-01-20 22:16:35] local.INFO: Request Captured {"hello":"there"}
```

for a given GET request `/?hello=there`

Comment: Facade's are disabled by default in lumen :)

Comment: Laravel (and Lumen) bootstraps the container as part of the application start-up. You're essentially just doing looking up an entry in a dictionary. Facade's on the other hand are registered using PHP's class_alias function :)

Comment: @TimLewis it doesn't spin up a new container instance unless there isn't one at all, there is only one application container instance ... nearly every helper function that is a shortcut is calling `app(...)` or `app()->...` check out `Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`

Comment: `app('...')` internally calls `app()->make('...')` so it doesn't make a difference

Comment: Thanks for the clarification you two   Removed my comments; I'm misremembering and they're not relevant anymore. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, started getting logs.